# Concentration of measure for products of expectations vs McDiarmid's

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega_1,\mu_1),\ldots,(\Omega_1,\mu_n)$ be discrete probability spaces. Consider the product space $(\Omega=\prod_i \Omega_i , \mu=\prod_i \mu_i)$. For every $\epsilon>0$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ Then

$$\mathbb{P}( | \mathbb{E}_{\prod_{i}\mu^{(k)}_i}[f] - \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f] |>\epsilon  )\leq \frac{4e^{\epsilon^2 k/8}}{\epsilon} $$. This the thereom 9. from the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.7654.pdf.

I suppose that $\mathbb{E}_{\prod_{i}\mu^{(k)}_i}[f]$ is the empirical expectation estimated from $k$ i.i.d samples. My question is why cannot we apply McDiarmid's inequality which is going to give a tighter bound? Is it because of we don't know if $|f(\boldsymbol{x}_1,\ldots,\boldsymbol{x}_i,\ldots,\boldsymbol{x}_k)-f(\boldsymbol{x}_1,\ldots,\boldsymbol{x'}_{i},\ldots,\boldsymbol{x}_k)|\leq c_i$? where $\boldsymbol{x}_i=(x^{(i)}_1,x^{(i)}_2,\ldots,x^{(i)}_n)$ is the $i^\text{th}$ sample. Assume that $\forall i:$ $\exists c_i\leq \mathcal{O}(1/k)$. Can we apply McDiarmid's under the above assumption of existence of $c_i's$?